# how to make data in access to only have 2 decimal number

Tags: ms-access

I think this might be a simple question but I don't know what's the answer

in access 2013 for my calculated field using Field properties I Set Format = standard and decimal place = 2,

and it shows the number with 2 decimal, but when I click on the field or when I want to show them in a `datagridview` in C# the number displayed with different decimal number. 
what should I do to round the number?

Answer (score 2):

The format property of a field has no effect on how the data is stored. If you want it displayed a certain way in your application, then you must format it in your application. The Winforms Datagridview column has a defaultcellstyle.Format property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: tanks, what about store the number into database with my preferred decimal number

Comment: If you want to store with 2 decimals, you have to round to 2 decimals first before storing.